# Windows computer restarts several times after power on

Tags: windows-10, power, reboot

The PC runs normally Windows 10 system for years till last week. Now every time I turn the power on, it will reboot after about 3 secs and repeat this for 3~5 times before it finally boots into the system. This happens with a cold start or wake from sleep, but never happens when I restart it. I've replaced the old CPU fan with a new one and tried different Memory stick slots, the issue persists.
Could anyone help me with how to find the issue part? I'm starting to think it's a power supply related issue now.

Comment: The system and hardware seem to be healthy and stable to me though, it rarely reboots or turns to blue-screen while I'm using it.

Comment: Start Event Viewer, go to *Windows Logs -> System*. See if you can find some explanatory error message.

Comment: @harrymc, I'm afraid there wouldn't be any in my case. I removed all peripheral items until only 1 motherboard and 1 memory left, the issue is still there. So I guess it's the power issue or even worse, the motherboard. :(